# Python: Printing Function To Call a Randomly Generated Class Object

Tags: python-3.x

Beginner python developer playing around and trying to make a card game. Working on my own system for randomly selecting cards.

```
import random

# list to draw random card from from:
card_names = ["ace_h", "two_h", "three_h"]

class Cards(object):

    in_play = False
    def __init__(self, face, color, value):
        self.face = face
        self.color = color
        self.value = value      

ace_h = Cards("Ace", "Hearts", 14)
two_h = Cards("Two", "Hearts", 2)
three_h = Cards("Three", "Hearts", 3)

random_1 = random.choice(card_names)
print (random_1 +".face")
```

If suppose `ace_h` was selected by the randomization, I was hoping that the print at the end would display the result for printing `ace_h.face` (which would be Ace). Rather, the print simply displays `ace_h.face` as a string, not the actual value associated with it.

How can I change this?

Note that simply using `print (ace_h.face)` gives the desired result.

Comment: Why not do `random_1 = random.choice([ace_h, two_h, three_h])` and then `print(random_1.face)`?

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but I'm not sure why? What is the difference between your code and mine, other than that mine refers to a pre-defined list?

Comment: Adding to @elethan: You don't even need named variables here. Just make a single `list` with the cards in it directly, because they're logically a collection of options, not a bunch of independent variables.

Comment: @user2390206: elethan's code is making a list of the actual objects, not strings describing them, and looking up the actual attribute, not concatenating on the name of the attribute.

Comment: @user2390206 as @ShadowRanger said, your code just prints strings while mine prints the return value of the `face` attribute on whatever `Card` is chosen. You could have your existing code work this same way if you `eval()` your string which will run the string as though it were Python code: `print (eval(random_1 +".face"))`, but using `eval()` is often discouraged because there are potential security risks involved (although since you are not taking user input it should be fine in this case, but randomly choosing from the objects not the names is a better option in my opinion).

Comment: Perfect, thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding about how to refer to things in Python.

In Python you have variable names:

```
ace_h = 1
two_h = 2
three_h = 3
```

You can call these values by name:

```
print(ace_h)  # => 1
```

You can put the values into another collection:

```
cards = [ace_h, two_h, three_h]
print(cards)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

You can print a specific element:

```
print(cards[0])
```

You can print a random element:

```
print(random.choice(cards))
```

But these all refer to the *values* `1, 2, 3`.

You can actually see that by checking the `id`:

```
print(id(ace_h))
print(id(cards[0]))
```

it doesn't matter if you're using the `ace_h` or `cards[0]` method to name the value, it's the same one.

This works the same for *everything* in Python - they're all objects. You can give them names of any kind, whether that's variable names, putting them in a list, or a dictionary - as long as `id(thing)` is the same, you're talking about the exact same object.

```
ace_h = Cards("Ace", "Hearts", 14)
two_h = Cards("Two", "Hearts", 2)
three_h = Cards("Three", "Hearts", 3)

cards = [ace_h, two_h, three_h]

print(cards)
for card in cards:
    print(id(card))

print(id(ace_h))
print(id(two_h))
print(id(three_h))

random_card = random.choice(cards)

print(id(random_card))

print(random_card.face)

print('random card is ace_h? {}'.format(random_card is ace_h))
print('random card is two_h? {}'.format(random_card is two_h))
print('random card is three_h? {}'.format(random_card is three_h))
```

You'll be a lot better off if you just think of variables as labels that you attach to values. In your case you're creating `Card` values and you're sticking the label `ace_h` on it. You're also putting that `Card` inside a list where you can refer to it by the name `cards[0]`. You could give it any number of names:

```
another_name = ace_h
cool_name = ace_h
king_arthur = ace_h
sir_lancelot = ace_h
minister_of_silly_walks = ace_h
```

Now every single one of those names refers to the exact same value. You can check it with `id`, and you can see that they all have the right properties with `print(dir(ace_h))` and `print(dir(minister_of_silly_walks)))`. And you can check that they are the same object with `ace_h is minister_of_silly_walks`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the objects into a list like this:

```
objectList = [ace_h, two_h, three_h]
random_1 = random.choice(objectList)
```

and then print the attribute you want:

`print(random_1.face)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you could go about doing this that immediately come to mind.

1. You can change your MO and have a list of variables initialized up front:

   ```
   import random

   class Cards(object):
       in_play = False
       def __init__(self, face, color, value):
           self.face = face
           self.color = color
           self.value = value      

   ace_h = Cards("Ace", "Hearts", 14)
   two_h = Cards("Two", "Hearts", 2)
   three_h = Cards("Three", "Hearts", 3)

   # list to draw random card from from:
   cards = [ace_h, two_h, three_h]

   random_1 = random.choice(cards)
   print (random_1.face)
   ```

   As you can see, I just reordered your code a little so that `card_names` could contain references to the actual `Card` objects instead of their names. That is probably the simplest way to do it.
2. You can access global variables by name. This is a bit more complex and probably not what you want, but the technique can be useful for other things:

   ```
   import random

   # list to draw random card from from:
   card_names = ["ace_h", "two_h", "three_h"]

   class Cards(object):

       in_play = False
       def __init__(self, face, color, value):
           self.face = face
           self.color = color
           self.value = value      

   ace_h = Cards("Ace", "Hearts", 14)
   two_h = Cards("Two", "Hearts", 2)
   three_h = Cards("Three", "Hearts", 3)

   random_1 = random.choice(card_names)
   print(globals()[random_1].face)
   ```

   This is more similar to your original code. `globals()` returns a `dict` containing all the names defined at the module level, including functions, classes, and variables, all keyed by name. `globals()[random_1]` will therefore be a `Cards` object (which I think you ought to rename to `Card` by the way).

   Inside a function, you could use `locals()` to get a similar `dict()` for the local namespace within that function. For example, in `Cards.__init__`, you could do something like `locals()['face']` to access the `face` parameter.